# Is it possible to restrict scrolling within a UICollectionView to a subset of the items in the collection?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

Is it possible to restrict scrolling within a UICollectionView to a subset of the items in the collection?

I have a UICollectionView that displays one item at a time. Each item takes the full width of the screen. The user can scroll horizontally between items.

At times I want to be able to restrict the user to scrolling between a subset of items based on certain conditions.

For example, view may contain items 1 through 20, but I only want the user to be able to scroll between items 7 and 9.

I have tried changing the contentSize to just the width necessary to display the desired items, then changing the contentOffset, but this does not work.

Comment: you should return proper value in `- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section` and keep track of model objects you want to display somehow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I spent like 6 hours researching this yesterday, but within minutes of posting my question I found the key to a solution here:

[Cancel current UIScrollView touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497192/cancel-current-uiscrollview-touch)

That answer describes how to cancel scrolling. What's neat is that the user doesn't see any scrolling behavior when they attempt to scroll outside the limits set for them; there is no flickering, nothing.

The solution I came up with is to determine the starting and ending offsets for the items I want the user to see, and then cancel scrolling in scrollViewDidScroll if the new offset is before the starting, or after the ending, offset:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    //Prevent user from scrolling to items outside the desired range
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x < self.startingOffset ||
        scrollView.contentOffset.x > self.endingOffset) {
        scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
        scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Swift` version:

```
  override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    //Prevent user from scrolling to items outside the desired range
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x < self.startingOffset ||
      scrollView.contentOffset.x > self.endingOffset) {
        scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = false
        scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = true
    }
  }
```